# 'No module named ' error occur while importing python newly create package from Pypi

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-packaging

I have created a simple python module https://pypi.org/project/ch-package/. There is no issue when downloading the package. But when it comes to import it throws an error

`from ch_package import name`

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-66be5dd42f11> in <module>
----> 1 from ch_package import name

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ch_package'
```

code

```
def name(text):
    return 'My name is Chanaka'
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
import setuptools

def readme():
    with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
        return fh.read()

setup(
    name='ch_package',
    version='0.1.1',
    description='This is a simple test project',
    author= 'Chaz',
    long_description=readme(),
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where='src'),
    package_dir={'':'src'},
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.5',
)
```

file structure

[image]

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: You ***really*** should be using https://test.pypi.org/ for testing like this.

Comment: `pip install ch-package==0.1.1`

Comment: The project directory structure is not correct, it seems like you misunderstood how the `src` layout works. There should not be any `src/__init__.py` file. But a `src/ch_package/__init__.py`. I recommend you look at this tutorial: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: Thanks for the support I found my issue and understand the structure and I will use the test platform to do such practice sessions in future.